# How can I calculate the frequencies of certain strings in rows of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am a R beginner and I have a huge dataframe, so here is a small reproduction of the dataframe.

I want to calculate the percentage of "U" and "A" for each dataframe row.

Not every letter appears in each row, so the simple prop.table function doesn't give me the desired output. I run into problems when not all 4 letters are provided in each row.

```
    ####Here is my sample dataset:
    a <- c("A","B","H","U","U","U")
    b <- c("A","H","H","U","U","U")
    c <- c("B","B","H","U","U","U")
    d <- c("H","H","H","U","U","U")
    e <- c("U","U","U","U","U","U")
    data<-data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)
```

I expect for each row a percentage for "A" and "U". If one of these letters doesn't occur in the row, the result can be a NA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rowMeans`

```
rowMeans(data == "A" | data == "U", na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 0.5 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Comment: how would I do the same if it were not rows, but columns? Just simply colMeans doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Olympia `colMeans` would work too. `colMeans(data == "A" | data == "U")` gives you percentage of "U" and "A" for each dataframe column.

Answer (score 2):

An option is to loop through the rows of the dataset and get the `mean` of the logical vector

```
apply(data, 1, function(x) mean(x %in% c("A", "U")))
#[1] 0.5 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

---

Or another option is

```
rowMeans(Reduce(`|`, lapply(c("A", "U"), function(x) data == x)))
#[1] 0.5 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

Both methods would also work when there are many elements to do the comparison